# Can I get inline blame (like GitLens) on WebStorm?

Tags: ide, webstorm

Just moved from VSCode to WebStorm. One of the features I liked on VS Code was the inline blame that came with GitLens. This allowed me to speak with team members who had written the code. Can this be done on WebStorm? (I know I can get the whole blame but I just want inline the last commit)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

UPDATED: corrected name to "GitToolBox" from "Jetbrains Toolbox"

This can be achieved through the GitToolBox plugin, it provides the exact same functionality as git lens, finally I found it!
This can be toggled from other settings> git toolbox global or git toolbox project (if you only want to configure per project)
See screenshot
[image]

Comment: Jetbrains Toolbox is a tool for managing your IDE's and different projects, I don't really know how to use it as you mention.

Comment: see my updated answer, the configuration should be available once you install the toolbox

Comment: Oh, you mean the `Git Toolbox` plugin, not the `Jetbrains Toolbox` as you previous mention.

Comment: I can't find `Other Settings`, or `Git Toolbox` in WebStorm

Comment: Wow, WebStorm's plugin search sucks.  I tried searching for "toolbox" and couldn't find anything, but searching for "gittoolbox" worked ‍♀️

Comment: @MaxCoplan your comment saved my day, I wouldn't have known otherwise, thanks sir.

Answer (score 39):

Install plugin [GitToolBox](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox). It has the same functionality as [Visual Studio Code's GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens).

```
File > Settings > Plugins > Marketplace
```

Comment: GitToolBox has the same functionality like GitLens on Visual Studio Code. Here the link to the plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox/versions

Comment: Just tried it and it is not even close as GitLens in VSCode. There are so many code history discovery tools missing compared to GitLens.

Comment: 2 years have passed,  is this GitToolBox as good as GitLens?

Answer (score 14):

As of 2022.2 versions, some JetBrains' IDEs have integrated this feature:

Settings/Preferences -> Editor -> Inlay Hints ::> Code Vision ::> Code author

If there is no such function, setting `vcs.code.author.inlay.hints=true` may help.

[image]

Comment: I don't see "Code vision" (using WebStorm 2022.2) - Is this a custom plugin you're using?

Comment: @friederbluemle My bad. I came here as a result of searching like `jetbrains inline blame`, didn't check every JB IDE.  Some of them has this feature enabled by default, while some could be activated by setting `vcs.code.author.inlay.hints=true`, not sure the whole story.

Comment: Just spotted it and in my effort to get rid of it, ended up here. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

In WebStorm, you can get all the blames for a file with the option:

VCS > Git > Annotate

Inline blame exact to GitLens is most probably not available as of now for WebStorm.

Answer (score 3):

Install plugin GitToolBox for inline blame like GitLens.

Comment: This appears to be just a repeat of some of the existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish exactly what you are asking by using `VSC => Git => Annotate`, for making it more easy to access, you could put a keyboard shortcut to it `Settings => Keymap` (Mine is `Alt-B`).

Answer (score -1):

on Mac:

Git -> VCS Operation -> Annotate with Git Blame

or

Just right click next to the line number and select Annotate with Git Blame

It will show the date and name of developer