# Is there a plugin similar to gitlens for pycharm or other products?

Tags: python, intellij-plugin

My question is very simple , as you read the title I want plugin similar to GitLens that I found in vscode. As you know with GitLens you can easily see the difference between two or multiple commits. I searched it up and I found GitToolBox but I don't know how to install it as well and I don't think that's like GitLens...

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox provide most functionalities provide by GitLens

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I get inline blame (like GitLens) on WebStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55473907/can-i-get-inline-blame-like-gitlens-on-webstorm)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use Git Toolbox [link here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox).

Features :

> **Git status:**
>
> - number of ahead / behind commits for current branch as status bar widget
> - ahead / behind, current branch, tags on HEAD as Project View decoration on  modules
> - status bar widget with detailed information and additional actions
>
> **Git blame:**
>
> - inline blame - show blame for line at caret in active editor

Comment: This is like GitLens?

Comment: Yes, you can install it easily by going in your settings (`CTRL + ALT + S` -> plugins -> marketplace), and searching for `git toolbox`.

Answer (score 2):

Open Settings on jetbrains IDE.

Go to plugins and look for git toolbox.

Install it and boom, its done!