# Intellij's GitLens Equivalent

Tags: intellij-idea

In VS Code there is a plugin called GitLens which allows the user to click on a line a view the last authors and changes of that line. It also allows viewing file changes from page commits. Is there an equivalent for Intellij?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I get inline blame (like GitLens) on WebStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55473907/can-i-get-inline-blame-like-gitlens-on-webstorm)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[GitToolBox](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox) is probably the closest, the inline git blame is nice.

Answer (score 6):

It is called *Annotate with Git Blame* and you can find in with contextmenu on the linenumbers or as an Action with Ctrl-Shift-A.

[image]

Comment: Is there another alternative? That option, wherever it is triggered from, is clunky as it takes up quite a bit of space next to the line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

GitLink plugin does the same job
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8183-gitlink

Comment: It does not. GitLink just links to the remote repo host - like GitLab or GitHub. There is no inline Git Blame.